# What's the word for something that uses more of something else relative to other things

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes something that uses more of something(energy,power, food, etc) in relation to other things?

Ex: Brandon's phone would last through the day as long as he didn't use a _______ app that would drain it fast.

Answer (score 1):

[Inefficient](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inefficient)

> b : wasteful of time or energy

[Wasteful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wasteful)

> given to or marked by waste : lavish, prodigal

[Greedy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greedy)

> having or showing a selfish desire to have more of something

The best choice may depend on context.

Answer (score 1):

I usually refer to stuff like this as resource or power hungry, so I'll go with hungry:

> "Brandon's phone would last through the day as long as he didn't use a
>   hungry app that would drain it fast."

From an article titled "These 5 apps are killing your battery":

"Netflix is a hungry app indeed".
[Battery-draining apps](https://www.androidpit.com/battery-draining-apps)

If you do a search for 'battery hungry' you'll find that a lot of people refer to devices and apps as power-hungry, less commonly energy-hungry. But, I restricted it to one word.

Answer (score 1):

For your sentence I’d go with “battery guzzling”:

> 1. To drink greedily or habitually: *guzzle beer.*
> 2. To consume to excess: *a car that guzzles gas.*

It's definitely used to describe things that use a lot of power. For example:

- [The Worst Battery Guzzling Apps](https://www.techlicious.com/tip/the-worst-battery-guzzling-apps/)
- [Pause (and then resume) Battery-Guzzling programs](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=4722)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple answers to your question. First, I'll address the word you are looking for your sentence: `Brandon's phone would last through the day as long as he didn't use a _______ app that would drain it fast.`

## **Power-hungry**

: It is a common lingo in mobile app technology. Power hungry apps are the one which consumes lots of energy or drains your battery fast.

> > Brandon's phone would last through the day as long as he didn't use a **power-hungry** (with or without hyphen) app that would drain it fast.

(good to know information)

From your sentence, it is clear that you are looking word particularly for app(s). But, when you talk about people. There are words which describe a particular type of hunger in person.

1. **megalomaniac** - a person who has an obsessive desire for power
2. **gluttonous** - given to excess in consumption of especially food or drink

Answer (score 0):

An example from a *book*:

*Mobile Security Products for Android (Philipp Kratzer, Christoph Gruber, 2014)*.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=KvfRBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=_yI51FDe3u&sig=ACfU3U2leqsFarBpfFtTpmF7Aoz9H_uCaA&w=1280

> The K. application checks for system leaks, viruses and Trojans,
>   **energy-wasting** apps, ...

(In your example, you'd need to change the article 'a' to 'a**n**'.)

Answer (score -1):

**hog**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hog)

> One that uses too much of something.

As in:

Brandon's phone would last through the day if he avoided app X that **hogged** its battery!.

Comment: I would say that **hogged** means that the hogger of a resource prevents others from using the resource. For instance people who **hog** a narrow road by driving in the middle of it prevent others from passing. Similarly someone who sends multiple large documents to a network printer at high priority thus stopping colleagues from printing at all can be said to **hog** the printer. I don't believe this applies to the **power-hungry** app which merely reduces the battery life. If the app uses a disproportionate amount of RAM or CPU, however, it could be said to **hog** that resource.